# React Navigation V.6 - Refetching data in a screen component only when back from other certain screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I'm using `React-Navigation V6` and I have 4 screens. 3 of them are accesible from the first through buttons,

In my first screen I have:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (navigation.isFocused()) {
      fetchSomeData();
        }
    }
}, [navigation.isFocused()])
```

This is because when I get back from two of the screens, I want to refetch the data. However, when I get back from the 3rd screen, I want **NOT** to refetch the data again.

How do I achieve this? I tried using a `dataFetchingFlag` variable in React REDUX, but it gets very, very messy, especially if there are more screens.

Answer (score 1):

Use route parameters. In the first screen call a function only if the certain parameter is set.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (route.params?.refresh) {
    fetchSomeData();
  }
}, [route.params?.refresh]);
```

In other screens set the parameter to true or false to get desired behaviour when navigating back.

```
navigation.navigate({
  name: 'First',
  params: { refresh: true },
  merge: true,
});
```

See [Passing params to a previous screen](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params#passing-params-to-a-previous-screen) for details.

The alternative way is to use [onStateChange](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#onstatechange) to listen to state changes and based on that call a function.

```
<NavigationContainer onStateChange={(state) => console.log(state)}>
  <Stack.Navigator>
...
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```